# How can I convert a double[] to double, for my return value? (Incompatible types error)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return, double

I am sorry for requesting help that may be basic; However, I tried every google and youtube post(at my level) and I cant seem to figure it out. Im attempting to make a method that returns me the roots of a polynomial to the 3rd power. The code works alone; however, when I attempt to put in a return function I make the return value an array (because there will be 3 roots, aka 3 values to return). When I do it I get an error beside the return function that says ["Incompatible types: double[] cannot be converted to double"]

```
    public class RootFinder {


        double[] roots = new double[3];

        double R(double a, double pa, double b, double pb, double c, double pc, double d, double rp4){
            /*Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);*/

     double dx, dc, root, root1 = 0, root2;

     double r1, r2, r3, remmainder, rp1, rp2, rp3;





     System.out.println("Enter the quotient coefficients followed by their power:");


  for(double i = -10; i<= 12; i++){ 

     dx = 1;
     dc = i;

      root = (-1*dc)/dx;

     r1 = a;
     r2 = (root*a)+b;
     r3 = (root*r2)+c;
     rp1 = pa-1;
     rp2 = pb-1;
     rp3 = pc-1;

     remmainder = (root*r3)+d;

     if(remmainder == 0){
         System.out.print("The Division equatates to: ");  


     roots[2] = ((-1*r2) + Math.sqrt((Math.pow(r2, 2)-(4*r1*r3))))/(r1*2); //quadratic formula (first root)
     roots[3] = ((-1*r2) - Math.sqrt((Math.pow(r2, 2)-(4*r1*r3))))/(r1*2); //quadratic formula (second root)

     //System.out.println("("+dx+"x"+dc+")"+"("+"x"+(double)root[2]+")"+"("+"x"+(double)root[3]+")");
     roots[1] = (dc*-1); // factor theorem a value (first root)


     break;
     }

         }

 return roots;   } 

}
```

I thank you very much in advance for helping, I have spent 5 days trying to fix it already but I don't understand what to do to fix it. (I even attempted putting "[]" beside every double, but nothing)

Thank you,
          Alejandro

Comment: You need to declare the method as returning a double[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use 'double[]' instead of 'double' as you want to return an array and not a single value. So, you should write something like that:

`double[] R(double a, double pa, double b, double pb, double c, double pc, double d, double rp4){ ....}`

And I mentioned that you tried to access values in array incorectly, in Java array indexes start from zero, so to access first value in array you have to write array[0] instead of array[1].

Comment: As I said Mr.Rahool, I thank you very much aswell!! and thank you for pointing out the indexes start, I did not run trouble into them; but I bet I would later in the code. Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

Your method declaration specifies a return of type `double` , however `roots` is of type `double[]` ie. an array of double.

There is mismatch in the return type mentioned in method declaration and what you are trying to return.

Try changing your method's declaration to this-

```
double[] R(double a, double pa, double b, double pb, double c, double pc, double d, double rp4) {
//Your method code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! You and Mr.Oleh have saved me from going crazy trying to keep finding the solution. I will sure learn from this Thank you!